# Finding weight of each grid in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, grid, statistics

So I have two vectors***(x & y)*** with x and y co-ordinate data points. I would like to put these points on  grid kinda like a scatter plot and count the number of points within each grid like the weight of each grid using Matlab.

What would you guys suggest is the best way to do this? Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to perform a 2D histogram of your x-y data.
You can use several tools from the file exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9896-2d-histogram-calculation

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1487

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14205-2d-histogram